# How to draw a circle in Swift 3

Tags: swift, draw, geometry

**Swift 3**
How to make a circle? The circle should be located at the center. Was certain radius. The background - blackblur. *Thank you*

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This isn't the place to come to request someone to write all the code for you. You need to show us what you have done so far and what specific problem you are having.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to make a circle draw a square and add a cornerRadius equal at width / 2:

```
let circle = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 100.0, height: 100.0))

circle.center = self.view.center
circle.layer.cornerRadius = 50
circle.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
circle.clipsToBounds = true


var darkBlur = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.dark)
var blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: darkBlur)

blurView.frame = circle.bounds

circle.addSubview(blurView)
self.view.addSubview(circle)
```

Good luck! :)

Comment: Thank! Do not prompt as the black is replaced by Blur?

Comment: It turns squared)

Comment: add this: circle.clipsToBounds = true

Comment: + circle.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear. THX! I love you)

Comment: Prompt please: how to remove and then this circle? self.view.willRemoveSubview (circle) is not working.

Comment: circle.removeFromSuperview()

Comment: Do not really understand. I have 2 functions. When you start the first function I need to draw the circle, when it starts the second function, I need to clean this circle. If I write circle.removeFromSuperview () function in the 2 says that does not exist. Yes, I'm trying to figure it out)